# How to add time delay

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to toggle between two images.
In my application there is one image, when this image is clicked another image comes an within a second it goes and previous image comes at the same position.the transition need to be visible to the user

My Code is

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent;
class aaa extends UiApplication
{
 public aaa()
{
    pushScreen(new bbb());
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    aaa theApp= new aaa();
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}
}
class bbb extends MainScreen
{
boolean flag=true;
BitmapField refresh1,refresh2;
HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
public bbb()
{
    hfm= new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_RIGHT);
    refresh2= new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("refresh_depressed.png"));
    refresh1= new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("refresh.png"))
    {
        protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) 
        { 
            if ( message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK ) 
            {
                synchronized (UiApplication.getUiApplication().getAppEventLock()) 
                {
                    if(flag)
                    {
                        hfm.delete(refresh1);
                        hfm.add(refresh2);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hfm.delete(refresh2);
                        hfm.add(refresh1);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }                    
            }
            return super.touchEvent(message);
        }
    };

    hfm.add(refresh1);    
    add(hfm);    
}
}
```

Comment: You have only declare the touchEvent in refresh1 Bitmap.
So please do the same thing in refresh2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please do `add` and `delete` the field in `eventlock`.

I have updated your code and put it as below.

```
boolean flag = false;
    public bbb()
{
    hfm= new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_RIGHT);
    Bitmap refresh2 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("refresh_depressed.png"));
    Bitmap refresh1= Bitmap.getBitmapResource("refresh.png");
    BitmapField bfield = new BitmapField(refresh2)
    {
        protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) 
        { 
            if ( message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK ) 
            {
                synchronized (UiApplication.getUiApplication().getAppEventLock()) 
                {
                    if(flag)
                    {
                        bfield.setBitmap(refresh1);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bfield.setBitmap(refresh2);
                        flag=true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }                    
            }
            return super.touchEvent(message);
        }
    };

    hfm.add(bfield);    
    add(hfm);    
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Another problem. this image is not visible now on the screen

Comment: you have only use 
refresh= new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/refresh.png"));

where is refresh1 & refresh2.
and remove "res/" from gerBitmapResource("..");

Comment: hey I hv done dat.. these mistakes were not dere in my actual code which i hv.. but still not getting this effect..the thing is only one effect is visible but the other is not visible.. i.e. second image is coming only

Comment: Please give me the whole class which you created.

Comment: I want to add remove and then again add these two fields on a single click.

Comment: check my ans i have update the code.
And i m sure that you have get your answer with my code.

Comment: again.. it requires two click events to change the image twice. Is there any other way.. What I want is.. On single click the image should go, another image should come up.. and again this image should go and previous image should come up.. But the user should be able to see the change

Comment: With my code i have only use one field so there is no use to make you click events......

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `invalidate()` after removing/adding any fields so that the screen is redrawn and the changes are visible.